# Hosting for Reactjs and Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, web-hosting

I want to host a website, integrating backend with Node.js and frontend with ReactJS. Actually, I have 2 different apps linked with RESTful services. A hosting domain offering Node.js already installed, can we host ReactJS app on  that panel too? I am confused about it.